# Why does my Delphi filter not work?

Tags: delphi

```
test := TFDMemTable.Create(nil);
test.CopyDataSet(TempUnplannedDemand, [coStructure, coRestart, coAppend]);
test.First;
    while not test.Eof do
    begin
      ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(test.FieldByName('demand_date').AsDateTime) +
                ' - ' +
                IntToStr(test.FieldByName('level').AsInteger));
      test.Next;
    end;
```

will show
24/03/2017 - 1
24/03/2017 - 0
24/03/2017 - 1
24/03/2017 - 1

```
  test.IndexFieldNames := 'level';

  //test.SetRangeStart;
  //test.FieldByName('level').AsInteger := 0;
  //test.SetRangeEnd;
  //test.FieldByName('level').AsInteger := 0;
  //test.ApplyRange;

  //test.SetRange([0],[0]);

  test.Filter := 'level=0';
  test.Filtered := True;

  test.First;
  while not test.Eof do
  begin
      ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(test.FieldByName('demand_date').AsDateTime) +
                ' - ' +
                IntToStr(test.FieldByName('level').AsInteger));
      test.Next;
    end;
```

will show
24/03/2017 - 1
24/03/2017 - 0
24/03/2017 - 1
24/03/2017 - 1

why test.Filter := 'level=0'; don't work

Sorry result after test.Filter := 'level=0' is RecCount = 0.

test.Filter := 'level = 1'=> RecCount = 3
test.Filter := 'level <> 1'=> RecCount = 1

Comment: Does `'Filter := 'level = ' + QuotedStr('0');` make a difference?

Comment: @LURD After 'Filter := 'level = ' + QuotedStr('0'); RecCount = 0.

Comment: Does `Filter := 'level is null';` changes anything?

Comment: What is the definition of 'level' in the database? i.e. what type of field is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if it can find records with level 1 but it fails with level 0 it can just be that 0 is reserved for something in filtering or that there is no 0 at all. Try this

```
filter:='level<1';
```

or try to access the value as a text with like statement (better solution)

```
filter:='level like '+quotedStr('0');
```

Also check your data type. It could be something you don't expect. If it's text then empty value could be stored in a table (and therefore you wouldn't find it)

Comment: This sounds like you are just trying things at random hoping they will work.

Comment: kind of... I can¨t test it right now and question dosn¨t contain details about a database. Also it's not really random. First two are really bad approaches but they should work (if there actually is zero value), second two are somehow better.

Comment: If the question is missing details, then vote to close it. Don't just write random stuff down in an answer. You could make suggestions in comments.

Comment: It's not random stuff... It should work both ways. If not then there is no 0 in a database,

Comment: I found it : test.FieldByName('level').AsInteger = 0 but test.FieldByName('level').AsString = ''

Comment: @TuanHoangAnh good :). I don't think that this should be the selected answer tho. I recommend you to create your own answer (that explains this) and mark it as accepted

Comment: @TuanHoangAnh Nowhere in your question is can be found `AsString`. Writing your own answer isn't going to help. The question is the problem. Before you do anything you should fix the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think that what he had in mind is that level datatype is a string but he accessed it as an integer so what he saw was 0 but what he really had was empty string. If he would know that he wouldn't ask :D. I can imagine that he didn't know because he doesn't have to be a creator of this structure..

Comment: Look at this question though. Asker leaves now, and cares no more. And this is left here in this state. The least we should do is downvote it, close vote it, and delete it. Then nobody else will ever happen across this and be confused by it.

Comment: I can also see the other answer as an accepted one but... It's not really answering anything. So with an edit mentioning right solution (or something like 'check level isn't string') that would be pretty much a correct answer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can see that. I was just explaining a poor guy :D.

Comment: The whole topic should just be removed, it can serve no purpose to any future reader.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139132/discussion-between-radim-nyc-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: See my update, which explains the result even in the Level column is an ftInteger type.

Comment: @MartynA and just like that both Q and upvoted A makes sence :D. I wouldn't expect null value in integer (I would comment your answer but I can't, yet). Perhaps will author change his answer selection (as he should)

Comment: @TuanHoangAnh: "I found it : test.FieldByName('level').AsInteger = 0 but test.FieldByName('level').AsString = '' Yes, that's how an ftInteger column containing a Null value behaves, or an ftString one for that matter.

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem must lie in something you have not included in your q.  The following works fine and produces the expected results for Level = 0 and Level = 1.  The `Test` dataset has fields ID=ftInteger, Demand_Date=ftDateTime and Level=ftInteger and is connected to a `TDBGrid` via a `TDataSource`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Test.CreateDataSet;
  Test.InsertRecord([1, '24/03/2017', 0]);
  Test.InsertRecord([2, '24/03/2017', 1]);
  Test.InsertRecord([3, '24/03/2017', 0]);
  Test.InsertRecord([4, '24/03/2017', 1]);
  Test.InsertRecord([5, '24/03/2017']);  //  <- this leaves the Level column as Null

  Test.IndexFieldNames := 'Level';
end;

procedure TForm1.ApplyFilter;
begin
  Test.Filtered := False;
  Test.Filter := 'Level=0';  //  or 'Level=1'
  Test.Filtered := True;
end;
```

Note the data row with ID = 5; this does not contain a value for the Level column, which FireDAC therefore treats as containing a Null value,  Because of this, the row will not be included in the filtered resylts, whether the Level is specified as 1 or 0 because Null matches neither of these.

Btw, a Null ftInteger column will return 0 as its AsInteger value, and so will an ftString one.

Comment: I second this. I would start having a look at the Level field DataType. He sets it AsInteger, but that does not necessarily mean it is an integer field.

Comment: @RadimNyč: Thank you for your support for my answer.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you for your answer. I don't see your answer after refresh chrome.

Comment: @TuanHoangAnh: "I don't see your answer after refresh chrome"  Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  Surely you can see my answer otherwise you wouldn't be thanking me for it?

Comment: @MartynA Sorry If I don't talk clear of my think. Please forgive it. Thank for your answer.